# Eliminating snakemake temporary directories

Tags: snakemake

In order to save the space on PC, I am working using a `temp()` function in snakemake. This is eliminating all the files `{sample}.dup.bam` inside the `dup` directory,but not the directory itself. How to improve this?

```
rule all:
    input: 
        expand("dup/{sample}.dup.bam", sample=SAMPLES),
        "dup/bam_list"

rule samtools_markdup:
    input:
        sortbam ="rg/{sample}.rg.bam"
    output:
        dupbam = temp("dup/{sample}.dup.bam")
    threads: 5
    shell:
        """
        samtools markdup -@ {threads} {input.sortbam} {output.dupbam}
        """

rule bam_list:
    input: 
        expand("dup/{sample}.dup.bam", sample=SAMPLES)
    output:
        outlist = "dup/bam_list"
    shell:
         """
         ls dup/*.bam > {output.outlist}
         """
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `temp()` function deletes all files which are not needed anymore in the workflow.
Since you specify in `rule all` that you need to create the file `dup/bam_list`, snakemake will not the delete this file, and thus, the `dup` directory. I'm even surprised all the bam files get deleted since you're asking for them in `rule all`.

**Tips**

You're defining a dependency between your rules:
`rule samtools_markdup` is needed before running `rule bam_list`. Therefore, you do not need to ask for `expand("dup/{sample}.dup.bam", sample=SAMPLES)` in `rule all`. The lasts will be created (and deleted as marked as temporary files) in order to create the file `dup/bam_list`.

If you need to delete a directory you can (probably) mark it as `temp` too as well as the `directory()` function:

```
output: temp(directory("dup"))
```

but once more, if any file in this folder is given to `rule all`, it won't be deleted. Working with directories is always a bit tricky since snakemake uses files (and their timestamps) to define the DAG.

Comment: thanks for a very extensive answer! So, I do not need to put all the output files in rule all as expand("dup/{sample}.dup.bam", sample=SAMPLES)? Or is this only for temp() files? Because for every single output I am creating with rules, I put in rule all. Thanks in advance for your answer

Comment: that's right, you do not need to put all files in rule all. Snakemake is a top to bottom workflow manager. Its goal is to create the files defined in rule all. In order to do this, it will parse the rules to see which rule creates these files and further down the other rules to create the necessary inputs if needed. In other words, if you define your inputs and outputs to run rule A > rule B > rule C > rule D, then you just need to ask for the outputs of rule D.

Comment: Thanks Eric, this is a very useful comment, as I didn't know and was creating 500 files in rule all :) thanks again!

Comment: Marking a directory as `temp` doesn't seem to work on Snakemake 5.26 (I don't have admin privileges on the system so can't update to a more recent version).